# How to pass username and password in external file into Excel Data Connection

Tags: database, excel, oracle, vbscript

I have numerous excel files which connect to our Oracle database. 
However, the connection details are stored in plain text in the connection details. 
These Excels are accessed by numerous different people.
I need to 'pass' the password and username from an external file into the connection in order to protect the database credentials.
The connections are only used by automated jobs on my machine. Therefore, other users don't need to use the connections.
My automated jobs use VBS scripts so a workaround in there would be best.

The portion of VBS which deals with this is

```
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("where workbook is located", False)
xlApp.Run "SampleMacroName()"


xlbook.Save
xlBook.Close False
set xlBook = Nothing

xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing

DisplayAlerts=false
```

Is there anyway to reference the password and username here?
Ideally we are looking for the simplest solution, so if we could hardcode them in this code that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to delete my connections in the database and use VBA code to replicate my connections in a series of SQL queries. The basis of the code that I am using is:

```
'Declare variables'
Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

'Open Connection'
objMyConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=***)" & _
"(HOST=*****)(PORT=****))" & _
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = ****))); uid=****; pwd=*****;"
objMyConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
strSQL = "Select distinct * From Temp_Final_Complaints_Report"

'Open Recordset'
Set objMyRecordset.ActiveConnection = objMyConn
objMyRecordset.Open strSQL

'Copy Data to Excel'
Sheets("Complaints Report").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset (objMyRecordset)
```

I can now encrypt the module where this is saved with a password.